# Query for multiple date ranges on a date field

Tags: entries

I'm able to successfully query a date field for a date range using this syntax:

```
{% set entries = entries.startsOn(['and', '>= '~firstDay, '< '~ lastDay]) %}
```

What I would like to do however is query that field for multiple date ranges at once with an `or` operator.

I can do this with other fields but the date range already using an `and` operator complicates matters so I can't do the same.

```
{% set data = data|merge(['or']) %}
{% for item in items %}
     {% set data = data|merge(['*'~item~'*']) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Any suggestions gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two queries, each for each range, and then merge them like this:

```
{% set firstRange = craft.entries({fieldHandle: ['and', '>= '~date1FirstDay, '< '~ date1LastDay]}) %}
{% set secondRange = craft.entries({fieldHandle: ['and', '>= '~date2FirstDay, '< '~ date2LastDay]}) %}

{% set entries = firstRange |merge(secondRange) %}
```

This is the way to do it. Also you should query for the ids, and then merge those, and then query by id.

I hope this will help.